# Linearising a system of ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

So I have this ODE: $$x''=\frac{-27}{13}x'+\frac{35}{13x}-\frac{4843}{283}$$
The question asks me to write a MATLAB script to linearise this ODE around any specified x value, as far as I know only first order ODE's can be linearised. So my first step was to break down this ODE into a system of first order ODE's:
$$x_1'=x_2$$
$$x_2'=\frac{-27}{13}x_2+\frac{35}{13x_1}-\frac{4843}{283}$$
The problem is now I have no idea how to linearise this even on paper, the method I would have used is: ()=()+′()(−), however of course this doesn't work in this case. I'm not sure what the question is even asking really, is it to find an expression which looks like this?
$$x''=mx+c\quad\text{or}\quad x'=mx+c$$
Even if you don't know MATLAB I am not sure how to approach this question even on paper so any help would be appreciated, also numerical approaches (like forcing the answer through bisection, estimate and check, is a viable way to solve this question) :)

Comment: Any ODE can be linearized. The question is: linearize around what solution? When writing it as a dynamical system as you have done it's normal to linearize around a fixpoint (as this allows us to characterize the fixpoint), i.e. around a point $(x_1,x_2)$ for which the right hand side of $x_1' = \ldots$ and $x_2' = \ldots$ is zero.

Comment: I have just one x value to linearise about, but the solution has to work for all values of x

Comment: If you are given to linearize about a given $x$ then you can do it directly in the first ODE. Take $x = x_* + \delta x$ and compute $f(x_*) + \frac{df(x_*)}{dx}\delta x$ where $f(x)$ is the right hand side of the ODE: $x'' + \frac{27}{13}x' = \frac{35}{13}x - \frac{4843}{283}$ - this gives you the linearized right hand side. For the left hand side you have $x = x_* + \delta x \implies x' = \delta x '$ and $x'' = \delta x''$.

Comment: See if this video helps you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJ3MiNhrMbs